# Spline plugin doesn't active after being installed?

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins, spline

I just intalled Spline plugin[image]

But then it is not activated on the toolbar [image]

What can I do right now?
I use QGIS version 2.10.1-Pisa. Windows 7 x64bit.

Comment: I've searched for the same problems on this site, but no one has encountered the same thing. I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have any layers loaded, that's why it's greyed out.

I've not used this tool myself, but it seems you need to

- select a vector layer,
- set it to edit mode.

Once you've done that, then the plugin's toolbar icon will activate, and you can use it to edit your lines. If you need to change the settings, it's under **Vector > Digitize Spline > Settings**

Comment: Thanks Kay. I'm a beginner. What I understand from your advice is that I have to open a new map and then the Spline plug-in will work. I've just done that and re-uploaded its picture here (see the second picture). It still does not work. The map I used is from "Natural Earth Quickstart Kit" found at QGIS tutorial site [qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html]

Comment: click on a layer name (e.g. 10m coastline), then right-click and select 'toggle editing'. You should see a pencil icon next to the layer name. Then the toolbar icon should be enabled. I suggest you read the [manual page about editing and digitization](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html) as well.